# Difference between radio waves and other electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Yes radio waves have different frequency and wavelength than others but it seems that radio waves are produced by sinusoidal current while other electromagnetic waves do not need need sinusoidal current to be produced. Is that true ?

Comment: All electromagnetic waves are produced by oscillating charges or dipoles. What's the source of your question?

Comment: all ? x. rays , gamma rays , uv, light waves etc ? are x- rays, gamma rays  produced from dipole ?

Comment: do dipole cause transverse or sine form of eleectromagnetic waves ?

Comment: x-rays and gammas are produced by rearrangement of charges in an atom or nucleus. Medical x-rays use accelerating charges.

Comment: @Alex: Without a charged particle, electromagnetism is not possible. Are you talking about producing electromagnetic energy without any charge in your hand?

Comment: i know electromagnetic waves are caused by accelerated charges. what i am confused about is that whether only sine current will cause sine electromagnetic waves or all other accelerated charges will also cause sine electromagnetic waves ? simple accelerated charges cause transverse waves thats what i know. but i assume that only sine(sinusoidal) current will cause the sine(sinusoidal) wave. as sine wave is transverse but all transverse waves might not be sinusoidal . thats what i need to confirm so i guess that radio waves are cause by sine current. @BillN

Comment: @Unnikrishnan what do you think about that ?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan "Without a charged particle, EM is not possible." So neutron stars do not radiate? Braking a neutron, it does not radiate?

Comment: A sinusoidal radio wave is a constant, single frequency. While that might be called a carrier (for AM, FM, or PWM), non-sinusoidal currents of the right frequency in an antenna will also generate radio waves - it just won't be a pure sinusoid.

Comment: @JonCuster so it means that em wave produced by the non sinusoid current will although be a transverse but will not be a sine wave ? right ? if the velocity of a charge is just increasing and increasing will it also cause a transverse wave ?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler whats your opinion on that ?

Comment: What sinusoidal current do you think is responsible for 21cm radiation?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler All electromagnetic radiation originates from charges. Neutron stars are not just made of neutrons.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler- Neutron stars are formed by the "melting of" electrons and protons into neutrons by the emission of Em radiation. See this : https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_origin_of_the_magnetic_field_of_a_neutron_star and http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FIAU%2FIAU4_S259%2FS1743921309030075a.pdf&code=5d8b77f9178e5931533e435a6523a1b7

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Bad example from my side. How about scattering of two neutrons? Was this process investigated? Does it happens in any case without loss of energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question appears to be about approaches to generate em radiation: For radio waves making electrons accelerate and de-accelerate in resonant circuits is fine, though by the time you get to microwaves you start to have to look at vacuum tube technology (for example, the klystron and its variants, the magnetron and the travelling wave tube) which is well advanced and still has important uses, particularly for those applications requiring power levels more than about 100 W. For lower power levels solid-state devices are desirable. Devices that are available include the Gunn diode (or transferred-electron device, TED), the impact-avalanche-transit-time (IMPATT) device and the metal-semiconductor field effect transistor (MESFET). More recently you will come across names like the modulation-doped field effect transistor (MODFET) (also referred to as the high electron mobility transistor (HEMT), the two-dimensional electron gas field effect transistor (TEGFET) or the selectively doped heterostructure transistor, (SDHT)). However, all of these devices generate em radiation by making electrons oscillate.

A quite different approach has been adopted for the generation of radiation by solid-state devices for the near-infrared (NIR) and optical frequencies, and is based on the quantum mechanical transitions of particles between discrete energy levels. For example, light emitting diodes (LEDs) and laser diodes both make use of the recombination of electrons and holes that have discrete energy levels in the conduction and valence bands respectively.

Most practical semiconductor lasers are based on the double heterostructure designs that have been successfully developed for wavelengths ranging from blue to the NIR, i.e. up to about 1.6 μm.

However, it is possible to generate light using nano antenna's, see [Can I use an antenna as a light source?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5046/can-i-use-an-antenna-as-a-light-source/5048) and the answer from Robert Filter.